# Does entity framework provide the functionality to update one graph with another dirty graph

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

Is there a method like UpdateComplexObject in EntityFramework (6)? Do I have to write this method myself?

I want the method to modify/delete/add to graph returned by Zoo.Animals(), with the new graph newSetOfAnimals.

```
Animals newSetOfAnimals = GetNewSetOfAnimalsMock();

ZooContext _db = new ZooContext(); // Inherits from db context
Zoo zoo = _db.Zoo().Include(x=>x.Animals).First();


_db.UpdateComplexObject(Zoo.Animals(),newSetOfAnimals); 

_db.SaveChanges(); //the database should be consistent after this method with the newSetOfAnimals graph
```

Comment: You can use _db.Animals.Remove  and _db.Animals.Add  but it would require looping